# NServicebus MessageHandlers in a different Project don't get hit

Tags: projects-and-solutions, nservicebus

**My problem:**
I have web project which implements NServicebus and should listen to messages.
Trying to keep my solution tidy I set up a different project for all my messagehandlers.
I now find that these messagehandlers do not get "hit" with messages.

To my understanding NServicebus scans all dll's in the debug folder of the web project to find any classes implementing IHandleMessages<>.
I referenced the messagehandlers class library project in my webproject and it appears in my debug folder, however it does not seem to get hit.

**What does work**

1. In a console sample project the inclusion of a referenced project which contains messagehandlers works as expected.
2. In my web app it works when I move my
   messaghandlers to the web app project itself.

Reading through the website http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/ I found that there are overloads for the Configure.With() method.
However:

- I do not know if I need them. They text only seem to suggest that
  this will limit the places where NServicebus looks for the
  implementations of the interface.
- these overloads do not exist in the Configure.WithWeb method which I'm using.

I can solve my problem by moving all the messagehandlers to my web project, but this does not seem like the best solution.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

When using NServiceBus in a web project, use `NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()` instead of `NServiceBus.Configure.With()`.

Also, in order to load message handlers in a web application, you need to include the `.LoadMessageHandlers()` line after `.UnicastBus()` as described in [Hosting NServiceBus in your own Process](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/#self-hosting).  Otherwise any `IHandleMessages<T>` implementations are not loaded and your web application operates as a send-only endpoint.